# How do I re export a named import as default in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export, node-modules

How to re-export a named import as default in JavaScript?

Tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
import { MyFunc } from './MyModule';
export default MyFunc;
```

I get an error:
`Attempted import error: 'MyFunc' is not exported from 'MyModule'.`

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why are you importing a function, and then immediately trying to export it? Why not just import into the file it needs to be in?

Comment: I'm importing it into `index.js` and then re-exporting it from there.

Comment: But _why_? What problem are you trying to solve? You're importing a function from `myModule` and then exporting it as a default export. Why can't you just import the function into the file that needs it as you've shown in your code?

Comment: This is just to save having to type one more path while importing. Example: `import MyComp from 'components/MyComp'` instead of `import MyComp from 'components/MyComp/MyComp'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above works:

```
import { MyFunc } from './MyModule';
export default MyFunc;
```

My mistake was trying to import from `index.js` as a named import.

Another way that seems to work is:

```
export { MyFunc as default } from './MyModule';
```